# Creating variable based on time since a specific date

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to generate a variable that is a numeric value of time of adoption which references to which wave a person adopted the behaviour. The waves will be created in time from date x, this may be a daily weekly or monthly and I will need to vary both date x and the time periods. here is a minimum working example

```
# create example df of person reference and date/times they adopted a behaviour 

y <- as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:01")

df <- data.frame(
person = c(1:10), 
date_time = c(y+days(1),    
              y+days(10),
              y+days(35),
              y+days(40),
              y+days(60),
              y+days(70),
              y+days(80),
              y+days(90),
              y+days(100),
              y+days(110)))
```

I want to split those adoption times recorded above as date_time into periods that could sequentially up from a specific date known as adoption time. Below is a way to create the output needed by month time bands from date y. However I may need to change y and the time bands to be days, weeks or months for different analysis. The resulting column in the below is a variable which numeric and relates to the month period that the person adopted the behaviour since date y i.e. 1st month, 2nd month etc. There will be a different number of adaptors in each month.

```
# create a sequential adoption time, in this case by month

df$adoption <- ifelse(df$date_time <= y+months(1), 1, 0)

df$adoption <- ifelse(df$date_time > y+months(1) & df$date_time <=y+months (2), 2, df$adoption)

df$adoption <- ifelse(df$date_time > y+months(2) & df$date_time <=y+months (3), 3, df$adoption)

df$adoption <- ifelse(df$date_time > y+months(3) & df$date_time <=y+months (4), 4, df$adoption)

df$adoption <- ifelse(df$date_time > y+months(4) & df$date_time <=y+months (5), 5, df$adoption)
```

my date frame is obviously a lot larger and I will want to reuse the function over and over with different time periods i.e. a day, a week, 2 or 6 months to create different adoption periods.  It may be a function exists for this or can be created? Sorry my function creation skills are not good enough to be able to create it!

Answer (score 0):

Your case is a bit unclear, but perhaps something simple like this works?

```
df %>% mutate(adoption = month(date_time) - month(y))

   person           date_time adoption
1       1 2014-01-02 00:00:01        0
2       2 2014-01-11 00:00:01        0
3       3 2014-02-05 00:00:01        1
4       4 2014-02-10 00:00:01        1
5       5 2014-03-02 00:00:01        2
6       6 2014-03-12 00:00:01        2
7       7 2014-03-22 00:00:01        2
8       8 2014-04-01 00:00:01        3
9       9 2014-04-11 00:00:01        3
10     10 2014-04-21 00:00:01        3
```

I think that this stops at 11, so if you need the absolute months then you need to do something like

```
df %>% mutate(adoption = month(date_time) - month(y) + 12*(year(date_time) - year(y)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - what I am after is a numeric value for adoption that is based on date_time being a number of days, weeks or months after a given date that I can specify. So if I specify the date as 01/01/2014 I want to know if the date_time is in in the 1st month, 2nd month, 3rd month etc. This extends beyond a calendar year, over many years so some date_times can be 100 months after the date I specify. Seems a function where you specify the date to start from and the frequency of cut periods is the right way to go otherwise I would have 100s of ifelse statements.

Comment: From what you say, it could also be done using a lookup table. Say that you have another data frame with columns as month_diff and value, then you could do something like ```adoption = lookup_table$value[lookup_table$month == month(date_time)] ```